# Carrying data within class scope in Spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing a spring boot component/service that takes a composite structure, enriches it, and converts it to a different composite structure.

Made up code example:

```
@Component
public class Enricher {
    private final ExternalCache cache;

    public Result enrich(Request req) {
        Result result = new Result();
        result.setLayers(req.getAllLevels().forEach(level -> toLayer(level)));
        return result;
    }

    private Layer toLayer(Level level) {
        Layer layer = new Layer();
        layer.setLevels(level.getAllSubLevels().forEach(subLevel -> toSubLayer(subLevel)));
        return layer;
    }
    
    private SubLayer toSubLayer(SubLevel subLevel) {
        // Need a property of the original request here!
        SubLayer subLayer = new SubLayer(cache.get(requestId));
    
        // ... Applying other logic to SubLayer here ...
    
        return subLayer;
    }
}
```

In order to create a SubLayer, I need a property of the request instance. Since every spring component is a singleton by definition, it shouldn't hold any request state.
Therefore, if I want to use a property of the request, I have to do one of the following:

1. Propagate it throughout the call stack - will work, but makes the code very complex and unreadable, especially if I need more than one property on the lower level.
2. Use ThreadLocal, set it at the beginning of the enrich() method, and clear it prior to returning from it - more readable, but also error-prone and kind of misses the point of a ThreadLocal.
3. Declare the bean as Prototype - doesn't help, because storing state is still problematic and this also might affect the caller bean (might have to turn it into a prototype as well).

Had it not been a spring bean, I could've just declared these parameters as fields and set them in the constructor, but I still want to enjoy the benefits of a spring bean.

Is there a way to get around this problem in an elegant manner?

Comment: `Since every spring component is a singleton by definition, it cannot hold state.` I'd think instinctively that a Singleton can hold state better than any other type of bean

Comment: BTW, I would propagate it through the call stack. Depending on the amount of properties you want, you might want to create a [Parameter Object](https://refactoring.guru/fr/introduce-parameter-object) to make your class more maintainable

Comment: @YassinHajaj clarified my statement regarding singleton and state. 10x for pointing it out. Regarding propagation, as I said, it'll work, but it's very cumbersome. Creating a Parameter object will further complicate matters IMO.

Comment: Sure but the problem is complex already, there's no problem in having a complex but maintainable solution. BTW, if your question does not get answered here, you can also try your luck at Code Review StackExchange, if you provide them with an already working piece of code of what you want to achieve